# $\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{10x}{20000-5t} = 5$, find $x(t)$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

By finding the integrating factor to be $-\frac{1}{5}\cdot(20000-5t)$, I've multiplied each component with it to arrive at:

$$(t-4000)\,\frac{dy}{dx}-2x=5t-20000$$

However, I am not uncertain on how to proceed, I understand I need to get the LHS together in the form $\frac{d(x,t)}{dt}$ so I can have a separable equation to derive, but I am not sure how to do this.

In most of the homework questions relating to this topic that I have been doing, I keep getting stuck at this part so any advice to tackle such problems would be appreciated.

Comment: Please use latex so it is readable

Comment: @ZelosMalum sorry, what is latex?

Comment: The writing system on this page and in programs to show proper mathematical notation

Comment: @ZelosMalum I haven't learned programming/coding, isn't my notation adequate?

Comment: The help center has [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) on MathJax.  If you looked at other questions you would see how much easier it is to read the math when MathJax is used.  At least you have used proper parentheses so the equations are well defined.  This is often a problem with slash fractions.

Comment: The solution accroding to Mathematica is:
$x(t)=-5\,(-4000+t)+(-4000+t)^2\,C$
if it helps you to find the solution path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake with your integrating factor, which should be
$$
\exp(\int \frac{2\mathrm dt}{400-t})=\exp(-2\ln(400-t))=\frac{1}{(400-t)^2}
$$
Now multiplying
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}\frac{1}{(400-t)^2} + \frac{2}{(400-t)^3}x = \frac{5}{(400-t)^2}\\
\Rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{1}{(400-t)^2} - \frac{2}{(t-400)^3}x = \frac{5}{(400-t)^2}\\
\Rightarrow (\frac{x}{(400-t)^2})'=\frac{5}{(400-t)^2}
$$
The tricky part being the sign. Now just integrate to recover $x(t)$
$$
\int(\frac{x}{(400-t)^2})'dx=\int \frac{5}{(400-t)^2}\Rightarrow \frac{x}{(400-t)^2}=\frac{5}{400-t}+c
$$
So $x(t)=5(400-t)+c(400-t)^2$

Comment: You're right thank you for that pick up. Could you please explain how you combined the dx/dt and x component to a singular part?

Comment: I think it is referred to as the "reverse product rule." Basically You just notice two pieces that look like a product was differentiated

Comment: Great, I'll have a look around for some Khan academy videos about that or something, thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: @rra117 no problem. Out of curiosity, what book are you using?

Comment: Not using a textbook but rather a question booklet my lecturer made (University of Melbourne)